# How do I select a blackboard bold font for Concrete math?

Tags: fonts, boldmath

I am using in my document the `concmath` package, but there is no blackboard bold font linked to the command `\mathbb{}` with this font package. I already asked this question elsewhere and I got this solution :

```
\makeatletter
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\map#1#2{\mapA{}#1#2\@nnil}
\def\mapA#1#2#3{\ifx\@nnil#3\empty \afterfi{#1}\else \afterfi {\mapA{#1#2{#3}}#2}\fi}

\protected\def\mathbb#1{\leavevmode\textup{\map\mathbbA{#1}}}
\def\mathbbA#1{\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\copy\z@\kern-\wd\z@ \kern.13em\box\z@}
\makeatother

$u=\{u(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb R^2} \quad \mathbb{NZQIRCOSABC}$
```

which slightly shifts the letter to produce the blackboard font, but this looks horrible for some letters.

**Is there a way to generate a decent looking blackboard bold font for concrete ?**

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are you asking about a blackboard-bold font, `\mathbb`, or a heavier math font, such as `\mathbf` or `\boldmath`?

Comment: I note that, when DEK commissioned the Concrete font for his book *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*, he also commissioned Hermann Zapf to create AMS Euler as its companion math font.

Comment: @Davislor I was asking for a font linked with `\mathbb` as I said at the beginning of my post. I don't want to use Euler, I really like the style of concrete math font.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! And that’s a perfectly reasonable preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use the [`ccfonts`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ccfonts/ccfonts.pdf) package, which is still being updated.  The `concmath` package is from last century.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
```

loads either the AMS or Concrete version of all the standard math alphabets.

Otherwise, you can pick a blackboard font you like from [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) and load that after `ccfonts` or `concmath`.

Be aware, either of these will give you pixelated METAFONT math fonts, unless you pay money for the Micropress Concrete Math font in Type 1 format.  You don’t need to do that, though: either you’re publishing in a journal that licenses the font, or you’re free to use a modern TeX engine that supports OpenType.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you might try pairing Concrete with the math symbols from the slab serif font GFS Neohellenic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format a MWE for TeX.SX

\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[
  Ligatures=Common,
  UprightFont=cmunorm.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunobx.otf,
  ItalicFont=cmunoti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunobi.otf ]

\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{cmunoti.otf}[range=it]
\setmathfont{cmunorm.otf}[range=up]

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Let \( (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \)
such that \( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon \).
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Concrete + GFS Neohellenic Math sample]

Or load `unicode-math` without `math-style=upright` to get italic math symbols more like the legacy packages.  Changing the option to `math-style=ISO` will slant your upright Greek letters, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format a MWE for TeX.SX

\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[
  Ligatures=Common,
  UprightFont=cmunorm.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunobx.otf,
  ItalicFont=cmunoti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunobi.otf ]

\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{cmunoti.otf}[range=it]
\setmathfont{cmunorm.otf}[range=up]

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Let \( (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \)
such that \( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon \).
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Concrete + GFS Neohellenic Math sample]

In either case, you can swap in a different blackboard bold alphabet with a command like

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=bb,
                            Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

Comment: Makes sense. I first discovered this font package in the LaTeX Companion from 2004 ! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The ‘amsfonts’ and ‘amssymb’ options: These options provide the functionality of the standard ‘amsfonts’ and ‘amssymb’ packages, but using the Concrete
> versions of the AMS symbol fonts and math alphabets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amssymb]{concmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but it doesn't change anything at all, I added the option `amssymb` and the bold font looks exactly the same as before. My question was in this post, if there was an other bold font that matches the concrete font style.

Comment: @Elyo There is a slight difference. Try removing the `amssymb` option and loading it as a separate package to see it. That being said, these are the blackboard-bold of the concrete font. If you don't like the font, you could use a different one (or are you trying to mix and match fonts within the mathmode?).

Comment: @Elyo If you do want to mix and match you'll need to find a different font you like and do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font.

Comment: ```\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[amssymb]{concmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
$x\in\mathbb{R}$
\end{document}``` Thank you for taking time to help me. I tried to compare the output between standard lmodern and concrete, and I can confirm that the output is exactly the same.

Comment: @Elyo Zoom in closely when you compare. The `amssymb` option makes the blackboard letters less smooth (I confirmed with your above comments code).

Answer (score 1):

The [concmath-otf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/concmath-otf) package has recently been upgraded to include upright blackboard capital letters, in normal and bold weights.
[image: Concrete Math OTF blackboard doublestruck capital letters, normal weight and bold weight]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{concmath-otf}

\begin{document}
    \[\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
    \mathversion{bold}\[\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]\mathversion{normal}
\end{document}
```

But since `Concrete-Math.otf` and `Concrete-Math-Bold.otf` are OTF fonts, one needs to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation ! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Elyo I have added bold letters to the answer as well.