# Combining two fonts with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex

I would like to use **Concrete fonts** as the *math font* (the same font use for math in the package `ccfonts` or `concmath`) for one document while using **GFS Neohellenic** for *blackboard letters* (because the `ccfonts` package doesn't implement blackboard letters for this font family) and I would like to set **Times New Roman** as *text font* **only**. I already asked a question on how to get blackboard letters for the `ccfonts` package here : [How do I select a blackboard bold font for Concrete math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622888/how-do-i-select-a-blackboard-bold-font-for-concrete-math). The following MWE was given to me to achieve what I wanted :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format a MWE for TeX.SX

\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[
  Ligatures=Common,
  UprightFont=cmunorm.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunobx.otf,
  ItalicFont=cmunoti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunobi.otf ]

\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{cmunoti.otf}[range=it]
\setmathfont{cmunorm.otf}[range=up]

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Let \( (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \)
such that \( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon \).
\end{document}
```

I never used LuaLaTeX and I don't understand how to mix Times New Roman and Concrete font in the same document. So here is my question :

**How can I mix Concrete font as math font, Times New Roman as main font et GFS Neohellenic for blackboard letters in the same document using LuaLaTeX ?**

I would like a MWE or links to ressources that explain how to mix fonts in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Do you want to use the math setup like in your MWE or do you actually want to use math symbols from Concrete?

Comment: I want to use the math setup like in my MWE and use Concrete as math font, not as main font as in my MWE, but I don't know how to mix this

Comment: cmunorm.otf, for example, has only 5 mathematical operators, and no Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols unicode code block. Do you want to use one of the `TeX Gyre ... Math` fonts instead? (look in `/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/`)

Comment: Now that there is a Concrete Math Opentype font (https://ctan.org/pkg/concmath-otf), is your question still valid?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, my question is still valid but was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request

"How can I mix Concrete font as math font, Times New Roman as main font et GFS Neohellenic for blackboard letters in the same document using LuaLaTeX?"

is not quite clear for me: Concrete fonts are *text* fonts usually associated with the AMS Euler fonts for maths.

One the other hand, Ulrik Vieth has issued (long ago, 1999) the `concmath` package which borrows the math letters (upright and italics) from the Concrete text fonts, unfortunately that is all metafont, not meant to be used with LuaTeX. I am not aware of any Concrete Math (Opentype) font usable with LuaTeX.

If you can accept Euler (upright) maths, you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\setmathfont{Neo Euler}              % No math italics
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase,range=bb]

\begin{document}
Let $(x,y) \in \symbb{R} \times \symbb{R}$
such that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon$.
\end{document}
```

which outputs as:

[image]

**Update 16th January 2022:** the new (experimental) `concmath-otf` package available on [CTAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0wRt.png) and in the latest TeXLive provides a Concrete-Math OpenType font usable with LuaTeX and XeTeX engines.

[image: ][2]] is the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Concrete-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
Let $(x,y) \in \symbb{R} \times \symbb{R}$
such that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will edit my request, as I understand that it's not clear. I use for my documents the `ccfonts` package which use the concrete math letters (like `concmath`). So I want to use concrete math font with GFS Neohellenic Math font for blackboard letters and times as text font

Comment: The font catalogue https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computerconcrete/ states: "Computer Concrete with Concrete Math is not available as Type 1 or OpenType."

Answer (score 2):

A reference comparison of some TeX Gyre Math fonts, so just an illustration, not an answer.

[image: texgyremath fonts]

Blue is the neohellenic bb.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\newcommand\blueneoh{\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase,range=bb,Colour=blue]}
\newcommand\testtext[1]{#1\par\setmathfont{#1}\blueneoh\noindent%
Let $ (x,y) \in \symbb{R} \times \symbb{R} $
such that $ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq \varepsilon $.\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\testtext{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\testtext{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\testtext{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\testtext{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\testtext{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\testtext{latinmodern-math}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice demo, but really ISO for maths? Does not resonate with me.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\setmainfont` command to `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`.  That sets the text font.